# Estimated execution plan show needed indexes?

Tags: sql-server

Ok,

I don't know if I am going crazy or not, but didn't the Estimated exexution plan use to show you what Indexes you would need to improve your performance?  I used to this at my old job, but now it seems I have to using the tuning advisor.  I don't mind the tuning advisor, but the way I did it before was so simple!

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In both SSMS 2008 and in SSMS 2012 see this is working fine for both estimated and actual plans.

Here is a quick example to show that estimated and actual execution plans will both show missing indexes:

```
USE tempdb;
GO

CREATE TABLE dbo.smorg(blamp INT);
GO

INSERT dbo.smorg(blamp) SELECT n FROM
(
  SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY c1.object_id)
  FROM sys.all_objects AS c1, sys.all_objects AS c2

) AS x(n);
GO
```

Now highlight this and choose estimated execution plan, or turn on actual execution plan and hit Execute:

```
SELECT blamp FROM dbo.smorg WHERE blamp BETWEEN 100 AND 105;
```

You should see a missing index recommendation. And you will see it represented here:

```
SELECT * 
    FROM sys.dm_db_missing_index_details 
    WHERE [object_id] = OBJECT_ID('dbo.smorg');
```

You can read more about the DMV here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345434.aspx

Also you should investigate [SQL Sentry Plan Explorer](http://sqlsentry.net/plan-explorer/sql-server-query-view.asp) (disclaimer: I work for SQL Sentry). This is a free tool that shows the missing indexes for estimated plans (if they are in the XML provided by SQL Server), doesn't have bugs like SSMS (where it repeats the same recommendation across multiple batches, even batches that don't mention the same tables), and generates actual execution plans *without* pulling all of the results across the network to the client - it just discards them (so the network and data overhead don't factor into to plan analysis).

Comment: Ok, but I was close.  it does what I am looking for versus using the tuning advisor.

Comment: hmmmm....I tried this and its not showing the indexes needed.  I even blew a way a primary key just to make sure.

Comment: The actual execution plan is not showing a missing index? Perhaps it's because the missing_indexes DMV doesn't know the index is missing, or because the plan is so trivial the optimizer doesn't think an index would be useful. Just because your table doesn't have a clustered index doesn't mean that every query would benefit from one. Did you look in `sys.dm_db_missing_index_details` manually to see if this table is even mentioned there? This is where the information in the plan comes from...

Comment: I only have two records in that table, and its for a throw away table that I am not using in my queries.  So if My Actual execution plan has an an issue and I need an index, it should show up in this table?

Comment: In that case the plan is probably far too trivial to require an index. If your query *does* have an issue, then yes an index that would have better supported the query will be noted in the DMV.

Comment: Guess it should be good practice to query that table and see what indexes you are missing?

Comment: Well, run a query you will typically run. Saying `SELECT * FROM table` will probably give you recommendations for a covering index that none of your real queries will actually use. Check the DMV periodically as it will store results based on actual queries from your actual workloads. `sys.dm_db_index_usage_details` can also tell you about wasteful indexes (those with lots of updates but few or no reads).

Comment: My system can't find sys.dm_db_index_usage_details, is this maybe a 2012 thing?

Comment: I think i found what you meant in sys.dm_db_index_usage_stats